# Need help(two dimentional array)

Tags: c++

How do I code a 2d array that would the user input different values for gold, silver, and bronze medals for each country? I know it's pretty basic but i really need help since I've only started c++ last week

```
Country          Gold Silver Bronze
Canada            0     3      0
Italy             0     0      1
Germany           0     0      1
Japan             1     0      0
Kazakhstan        0     0      1
Russia            3     1      1
South Korea       0     1      0
United States     1     0      1
```

Comment: You may try a `std::map`, with a `std:string` as key and a `std:tuple` as value. Or use a specific struct with the 4 fields. It depends how you will use it. 1D array in the last case

Comment: Or create a `struct` with `std::string` and `std::array<int,3>` and then create a `std::vector<your_struct>`? Several examples in [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936687/3422102)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: See also the example for [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you expect the user to be able to do?

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...) then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Answer (score 2):

For any particular country, you might have an array to represent the row that holds the medal counts. Each column in a row would be associated with gold, silver, or bronze.

Ignoring country for now, you might do something like:

```
// Hold all the medal values
std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> medal_table;

// Skip title line
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

std::string country;
int gold, silver, bronze;
while (std::cin
       >> country
       >> gold
       >> silver
       >> bronze) {
    std::array<int, 3> row{gold, silver, bronze};
    medal_table.push_back(row);
}
```

<sub>*Note:* the parsing of the country isn't perfect, because some of the country names actually consist of two strings. I'll leave solving that as an exercise.</sub>

But, we have now lost the association between the country and the medal counts. You could create another vector to manage that. For example:

```
std::vector<std::string> country_table;
```

And then, inside the loop, push the country value in when you push in the row.

```
    medal_table.push_back(row);
    country_table.push_back(country);
```

Now, there is a correspondence between the rows in `medal_table` and the rows in `country_table`.

The disadvantage of this approach is that if you want to know the medal counts for a particular country, you will have to scan `country_table` first to find the country. The found index in `country_table` is then used on `medal_table` to find the medal counts.

If you can move away from a strictly 2 dimensional array into one that allows 2 dimensional indexing, you can directly map a country name to the row representing the medal counts.

```
std::map<std::string, std::array<int, 3>> medal_map;
```

Then, instead of populating corresponding arrays, you can populate a single map.

```
    medal_map[country] = row;
```

Now, to find the medal counts for a particular country, you simply index `medal_map` by the name of the country.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `std::tuple` would be to create the `std::tuple<std::string, int, int, int>` and then add each tuple to a `std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, int, int>>`.

Since you can have whitespace included in the country names, it would be simpler to read the country names with `getline()` and then use normal iostream for gold, silver and bronze. After creating the `std::tuple` from the values, use the `.push_back()` member function of `std::vector` to add the tuple to your vector.

To output the values, you separate each `std::tuple` into separate values using `std::tim` and then output, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {
    
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, int, int>> medals{};   /* vector tuples */
    std::string country{};      /* string for country input */
    int g, s, b;                /* integers for gold, silver, bronze input */
    
    while (1) { /* loop continually */
        std::cout << "enter country: ";         /* prompt and read country */
        if (!getline (std::cin, country) || !country.length())
            break;
        
        std::cout << "  gold silver bronze: ";  /* prompt and read gold, silver, bronze */
        if (!(std::cin >> g >> s >> b)) {
            std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
            break;
        }   /* remove up to \n from stdin */
        std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        
        medals.push_back (std::make_tuple (country, g, s, b));  /* add tuple to vector */
    }
    
    std::cout << "\nCountry          Gold Silver Bronze\n";     /* output heading */
    for (const auto& t : medals) {              /* loop outputting formatted values */
        std::tie (country, g, s, b) = t;
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(17) << country << std::right <<
                    std::setw(2) << g << std::setw(6) << s << std::setw(7) << b << '\n';
    }
}
```

(**note:** you have to remove characters up to the `'\n'` after reading the `int` values before calling `getline()` again)

**Exmaple Use/Output**

You simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty-line to end input:

```
$ ./bin/tuple_metals
enter country: Canada
  gold silver bronze: 0 3 0
enter country: Italy
  gold silver bronze: 0 0 1
enter country: Germany
  gold silver bronze: 0 0 1
enter country: Japan
  gold silver bronze: 1 0 0
enter country: Kazakhstan
  gold silver bronze: 0 0 1
enter country: Russia
  gold silver bronze: 3 1 1
enter country: South Korea
  gold silver bronze: 0 1 0
enter country: United States
  gold silver bronze: 1 0 1
enter country:

Country          Gold Silver Bronze
Canada            0     3      0
Italy             0     0      1
Germany           0     0      1
Japan             1     0      0
Kazakhstan        0     0      1
Russia            3     1      1
South Korea       0     1      0
United States     1     0      1
```

There are a number of ways to do this, this just being one approach. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Nifty `tuple` example!

Comment: Thank you, it was kinda ironic the switch in answers. My comment was string array<int, 3>, but then I ended up with a tuple. `:)`